# Convering a Character to HMS in R

Tags: r, character, huawei-mobile-services

I am inquiring to learn how I can convert a character to hms so that I can accurately plot the mean of a series of album lengths that are in hh:mm:ss format. Here's my code. It doesn't work.

```
#Create labels for the mean
meanHours <- music %>%
  select(AlbumHours) %>%
summarise(hrsMean = albumHRSmean, na.rm=TRUE)  %>%
  strptime(hrsMean, "%H:%M:%S") %>%
  mutate(label_hrsMean = paste0("Mean of Hours: ",(hrsMean)))
```

Comment: I do love that this has been tagged `huawei-mobile-sevices` somehow as a result of `hms` being entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `hms()` function from `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

meanHours <- music %>%
  select(AlbumHours) %>%
  summarise(hrsMean = albumHRSmean, na.rm=TRUE)  %>%
  mutate(hrsMean = hms(hrsMean),
         label_hrsMean = paste0("Mean of Hours: ",(hrsMean)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and I was able to plot the mean on the scatterplot.